# How to send js string from chrome extension content script to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a chrome extension which will scrap text data from certain websites(when i visit the page) and save it in a SQL database. The js for data scrapping is working fine and it can save all data I need in a string. Now I want to send that js string to a localhost php file I have using XAMPP, but looks like the php can't receive the string I send.
My js code snippet for sending data

```
$.post("http://localhost:8080/naukri/index.php",            //link to localhost php  
    {variable: finalVal},                               //finalVal contains the string I want to send  
    function(data) {if (data != "") {
    alert('We sent Jquery string to PHP : ' + data);                //alert shows the string I am sending  
    window.open("http://localhost:8080/naukri/index.php");  //open php page to confirm if data received or not 
    console.log(data);    //SOLVED use this instead of window.open()  
    }  
});
```

My php code

```
$test;  
$test = $_POST['variable'];  
echo $test;  //just checking if string received or not, I will worry about inserting into SQL later.
```

Now the alert shows the correct string that I am trying to send but the php page shows this error

```
" Notice: Undefined index: variable in C:\xampp\htdocs\naukri\index.php on line 4"
```

I think which means that the php file haven't received the string I am sending.
Please tell me how to successfully send string from js to php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that your opening your calling your php file twice.

- The first thing your doing is sending a post request to your php file.
- Then your trying to check whether it was received or not by opening your php page in another window (via a get request).

These two calls to your file are completely separate, and therefore the data passed in the first request is not available in your second as php is stateless.

If you want to check whether your web-extention is working properly with your php, you'll have to check what the ajax request actually returned, rather than calling the page a second time. Open up your browsers developer tool's network tab to check.

Comment: yeah I figured out what I was doing wrong, used console.log(data) instead of window.open and now its showing the data i sent in console now.